# Does creating a GUILayoutOption allocate memory?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add some options to a GUI element. For example, like this:

```
GUILayout.Button("Click me!", GUILayout.Width(someValue));
```

My question is whether the call to `GUILayout.Width()` creates a new object on the heap, caches the value, or returns a struct? Because if it creates a new instance each time, then it may be worth creating it once at the beginning instead of creating it at every call to `OnGUI()`, to avoid excess garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new instance of `GUILayoutOption` everytime you call `GUILayout.Width()`. Below are some snippets from Unity source code supporting this:

**It creates a new instance on every call to `GUILayout.Width()`**
[GUILayout.cs -- Line #903](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/618375ddc65fa50fee792c84be81b9761a416504/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/GUILayout.cs#L903)

```
public static GUILayoutOption Width(float width)
{
    return new GUILayoutOption(GUILayoutOption.Type.fixedWidth, width);
}
```

**GUILayoutOption is a class, not a struct**
[GUILayoutOption.cs -- Line #5](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/618375ddc65fa50fee792c84be81b9761a416504/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/GUILayoutOption.cs#L5)

```
public sealed class GUILayoutOption
```

**On an other note:** The call to `GUILayout.Button` takes a `params GUILayoutOption[]` so it will implicitly create a new array on each call. If you want to go as far as caching the `GUILayoutOption` you might aswell cache them in array and pass that to `GUILayout.Button()`.